# Swapping Materials and Obj files with Three.js and adding a UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm a huge fan of three.js : )

I'd like to make a simple obj viewer of a male .obj model trying on different pants in three.js.

I have the .obj loader working ok for the moment, but I don't know how to add a simple UI to swap the .obj pants and their textures. The code I have at the moment is below. Any help in 1) adding obj and texture swapping functionality and 2) incorporating a simple, customizable UI would be awesome! (ideally not Dat GUI) For now, my assets are only avatar.obj / avatar.mtl and pants1.obj / pants1.mtl, but I would love to build in code to swap for pants2.obj, pants3.obj, and different .mtls.

Please note, I've reviewed the Bugatti example at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cars and was not able to understand which components to add to my code to add similar functionality. I'm just starting to learn three.js and javascript and would love anyone's help to explain how to do this! Thank you so much in advance! Any other thoughts on how to improve my code would be greatly appreciated as well.

Humbly yours,

-Platypus

```
<HTML>
    <title> OBJ Viewer and Swapping Assets</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script src="js/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>


        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>




    <div id="webGL-container"></div>

    <style>

        body{
            margin:0;
            overflow:hidden;

            }
        </style>

        <body>

            <div id ="webGL-container">
            </div>

            <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 

            <script>
            $(function(){
/*Work on v72  */

    /*global variables*/
    var scene, camera, renderer;
    var controls;
    var stats;
    var spotLight, cube;
    var SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;


    function init(){
        /*creates empty scene object and renderer*/
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 1000);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

        renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
        renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

        /*add controls*/
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );


        /*Camera*/
        camera.position.x = 125;
        camera.position.y = 80;
        camera.position.z = 125;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        /*Lights*/
        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );
        scene.add( ambient );

        spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
        spotLight.position.set( 100, 100, 500 );
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 8;
        spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 30;
        spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
        spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
        spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
        spotLight.name = 'Spot Light';
        scene.add( spotLight );

        var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, .4 );
        scene.add( light );


        //Platform Texture
        var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'Assets/wood/wood3.jpg' );



        var platform = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 5, 32 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {


            side: THREE.Doubleside,

            shininess: 100,
            specular: 0xffffff,
            map: texture1,
            shading: THREE.SmoothShading

            } );
        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( platform, material );


        cylinder.receiveShadow = true;
        cylinder.position.set( 0, -2, 0 );
        cylinder.castShadow = true;
        scene.add( cylinder );




        /*model loading*/
        var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
        }
        };

        var onError = function ( xhr ) { };


        var mtlLoader1 = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader1.setBaseUrl( 'Assets/obj/' );
        mtlLoader1.setPath( 'Assets/obj/' );
        mtlLoader1.load( 'pants1.mtl', function( materials ) {


        materials.preload();


        var objLoader1 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader1.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader1.setPath( 'Assets/obj/' );
        objLoader1.load( 'pants1.obj', function ( object ) {

            object.position.y = 0;
            scene.add( object );

            }, onProgress, onError );

            });



        var mtlLoader2 = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader2.setBaseUrl( 'Assets/obj/' );
        mtlLoader2.setPath( 'Assets/obj/' );
        mtlLoader2.load( 'avatar.mtl', function( materials ) {

        materials.preload();

        var objLoader2 = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader2.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader2.setPath( 'Assets/Joe_Boxer_L/' );
        objLoader2.load( 'avatar.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = 0;
        //object.rotate(10);

        scene.add( object );

        }, onProgress, onError );

        });




        $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);

    }

    function render() {}

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();



        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    init();
    animate();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    });

}); 

</script>
        </body>

        </HTML>
```

Comment: As it stands, your question is not very suitable for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. This is *not* a forum, you can't have a *conversation* here. What you need to do is break your story up into individual, specific, well informed questions that can than be individually answered by the community. That way you'll actually get *answers*.

Comment: Ok...could someone perhaps point me in the right direction regarding swapping .obj files using three.js? That would be very helpful.